# Android apikey Not Supported for Google Map

Tags: android, api-key

I got a fingerprint

```
73:F9:85:F8:14:56:4A:E7:D1:D4:31:6F:23:AA:4D:38:EB:16:5C:EE
```

but when i used to generate api Key using this link

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html it shows
"The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back
button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint".

If i omit last four Character and use

```
73:F9:85:F8:14:56:4A:E7:D1:D4:31:6F:23:AA:4D:38
```

it generate api key that not support to create Google map in android Application

Comment: Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) or Certificate fingerprint (MD5) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set Your java Path in Command Prompt And also set debug.keystore path.

 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin >
 keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\UserName\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

And use `MD5 fingerprint` .....

Answer (score 0):

Super easy with Eclipse [Keytool](http://www.icodeya.com/2011/04/how-to-get-your-md5-fingerprint-for.html) addon-tool

You can use the android.debug key for debugging or your own key for using it on a device.